# Postgres group by similarity result

Tags: postgresql

I have some tables with properties of Name and Result each.
i want to join tables by name similarity but limit the result arrived from each group of similarity into max 2 results.

```
CREATE TABLE data_a(
Id serial primary key,
Name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
Result INT4 NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE data_b(
Id serial primary key,
Name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
Result INT4 NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO data_a
    (Name, Result)
VALUES
    ('Todd', 2),
    ('John', 5);

INSERT INTO data_b
    (Name, Result)
VALUES
    ('Johns', 5),
  ('Todi', 3),
    ('Tod', 4),
    ('Todd', 5),
    ('John', 1),
('Jon', 1),
('Johny', 1),
('Johnny', 1),
('Johni', 1);
```

i would like to run a query that join both tables by name similarity and limit results to up to 2 results

```
SELECT da.Name as Name_a,db.Name , similarity(da.Name,da.Name) > 0.5
FROM data_a da 
JOIN data_b db 
ON  da.Name % db.Name
GROUP BY da.Name,db.Name
ORDER BY similarity 
LIMIT 2
```

and recive

```
|Name_a|Name_b|similarity|
|------|------|----------|
|Todd  | Todd | 1        |
|------|------|----------|
|Todd  | Tod  |0.8       |
|------|------|----------|
|John  | John |1         |
|------|------|----------|
|John  | Johny|0.76      |
|------|------|----------|
```

currently i get

```
|Name_a|Name_b|similarity|
|------|------|----------|
|Todd  | Todd | 1        |
|John  | John |1         |
```

it seems that i'm not using correctly in group by , how can i group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the LIMIT separately per da.Name, you would have to do it in a LATERAL subquery:

```
SELECT da.Name as Name_a,db.Name , similarity(da.Name,db.Name)
FROM data_a da CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
(
    SELECT db.Name
    FROM data_b db
    WHERE  da.Name % db.Name
    ORDER BY similarity(da.Name,db.Name) DESC 
    LIMIT 2
) db;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lateral join to map each name to a name from the first table, then truncate the result to 2 values for each name.

```
with data AS (
  select 
    da.name da_name, 
    db.name db_name, 
    similarity(da.name::text, db.name::text) similarity 
  from 
    data_a da 
    left join lateral (
      select 
        data_b.Name 
      from 
        data_b
    ) db ON da.Name like '%' || db.Name || '%' 
    or db.Name like '%' || da.Name || '%'
) 
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      row_number() over (
        partition by da_name 
        order by 
          similarity
      ) r, 
      t.* 
    FROM 
      data t
  ) x 
WHERE 
  x.r <= 2;
```

Demo in [sql<>daddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/ad3509a3)